# GetPrint Request with SELECTION parameter

Tags: qgis, wms, qgis-server, getprint

According to informations from this [site](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/qgis_server_tutorial#SELECTION-parameter) I can use "SELECTION parameter" with GetPrint Request. I tried to achieve this but without success. With GetMap request everything is OK.

Can some one help me with this?

Here are my tests - URL's and result images.

WMS GetMap request without selection:

```
http://192.168.1.14/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv?
map=/home/user/map.qgs&
SERVICE=WMS&
VERSION=1.3.0&
REQUEST=GetMap&
CRS=EPSG:2180&
BBOX=-1,-1,1,1&
FORMAT=image/png&
LAYERS=test&
WIDTH=500&
HEIGHT=500
```

[image: WMS GetMap Request without selection]

WMS GetMap request with selection:

```
http://192.168.1.14/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv?map=/home/user/map.qgs&
SERVICE=WMS&
VERSION=1.3.0&
REQUEST=GetMap&
CRS=EPSG:2180&
BBOX=-1,-1,1,1&
FORMAT=image/png&
LAYERS=test&
WIDTH=500&
HEIGHT=500&
SELECTION=test:0
```

[image: WMS GetMap request with selection]

WMS GetPrint request without selection:

```
http://192.168.1.14/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv?map=/home/user/map.qgs&
SERVICE=WMS&
VERSION=1.3.0&
REQUEST=GetPrint&
CRS=EPSG:2180&
map0:EXTENT=-1,-1,1,1&
FORMAT=image/png&
LAYERS=test&
TEMPLATE=1
```

[image: WMS GetPrint request without selection]

And WMS GetPrint request with selection (image look exactly same):

```
http://192.168.1.14/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv?map=/home/user/map.qgs&
SERVICE=WMS&
VERSION=1.3.0&
REQUEST=GetPrint&
CRS=EPSG:2180&
map0:EXTENT=-1,-1,1,1&
FORMAT=image/png&
LAYERS=test&
TEMPLATE=1&
SELECTION=test:0
```

Here example with FILTER parameter:

```
http://192.168.1.14/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv?map=/home/user/map.qgs&
SERVICE=WMS&
VERSION=1.3.0&
REQUEST=GetPrint&
CRS=EPSG:2180&
map0:EXTENT=-1,-1,1,1&
FORMAT=image/png&
LAYERS=test&
TEMPLATE=1&
FILTER=test:%20%22FID%22%20=%200
```

[image: WMS GetPrint request with FILTER]

Comment: It looks like a bug. Did you open a ticket?

Comment: Yes, I opened bug report http://hub.qgis.org/issues/13459